# How do I rotate an image from a console using GIMP?

Tags: command-line, gimp, gimpfu

I am trying to run GIMP using console commands. All I want it to do is rotate an image 90 degrees.  I added GIMP to my environmental variables so that I can call it from a console window. I also put the picture I want to rotate in my root console directory to make it easy to open.

I read the [GIMP Batch Mode](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) guide and came up with this command:

```
gimp-2.10 -i -b '(gimp-image-rotate plot.png 0)' -b '(gimp-quit)'
```

The "0" after "plot.png" is supposed to tell it to rotate 90 degrees. This opens a GIMP output window and outputs two messages saying "batch command executed successfully". However, it never rotates the image.

Any idea why the command I have entered is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gimp-image-rotate` rotates a loaded image and not a file that contains an image. So you have to

1. obtain an image by loading it from a file (see the `gimp-file-load` or `gimp-file-{type}-load` calls),
2. rotate the image,
3. save the result (`gimp-file-{type}-save` (caution: these calls save a layer, not the whole image)).

But for simple manipulations you are better off using a toolbox designed to be called from scripts such as ImageMagick:

```
magick mogrify -rotate 90 plot.png
```